# In-App Messaging Firebase click listener in React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-in-app-messaging

I'm integrate [In-App Messaging Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging) into my app, which is built with React Native and Expo, and I need to access the custom data specified in the Firebase console when I create the message [(custom data in Firebase console)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ussl5.png).

I looked through the [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/in-app-messaging) and didn't find a function (like a button click listener) that can help me with that.

I'm trying to use a Linking listener, but it doesn't work.

```js
Linking.addEventListener('url', (event) => {
    console.log("Linking event:", event.url);
    setUri(event.url);
});
```

I want to retrieve the custom data in the In-App message and perform whatever logic the client needs. Does anyone have an idea how I can achieve this?